# error syntax when use inner join to remove duplicate in sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I tried to remove duplicate in my table Stories but it gave me this error:

E/SQLiteLog( 9363): (1) near "t1": syntax error in "DELETE t1 FROM Stories  t1 INNER JOIN Stories  t2 WHERE t1._id < t2._id AND t1.storyID = t2.storyID;"
E/flutter ( 9363): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "t1": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DELETE t1 FROM Stories  t1 INNER JOIN Stories  t2 WHERE t1._id < t2._id AND t1.storyID = t2.storyID;) sql 'DELETE t1 FROM Stories  t1 INNER JOIN Stories  t2 WHERE t1._id < t2._id AND t1.storyID = t2.storyID;' args []}

I don't know why the syntax is wrong. When I run this in mysql online, it worked as well.

Can somebody tell me why , please @@

here is my sqflite code:

```
await db.rawQuery(''
        'DELETE t1 FROM Stories t1 '
        'INNER JOIN Stories t2 '
        'WHERE t1._id < t2._id AND '
        't1.storyID = t2.storyID;'
        '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that sqflite have a specific function for this one.
What I need to do is just add UNIQUE to the field I want it be not duplicate, and add conflictAlgorithm.replace in db.insert.
That's all. Hope this can help somebody.